# SpriteKit - How Do I Make a Prize Wheel Slow Down With A "Flapper"?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to make a wheel of fortune style game using sprite kit. But I'm stuck.

Okay, I have two SKSpriteNode s (with physics bodies). The wheel, which spins just fine, and the "flapper" (aka the thing that slows the prize wheel down and indicates what prize you won. The flapper keeps getting pushed upward, rather than pivoting and slowing down the wheel.

My questions are:

A) How do I keep the "flapper" from moving up instead of stay stationary at the top and slowing down the wheel.

B) How do I make the "flapper bend instead of simply being pushed.

C) Why won't the wheel spin more than once? (Note: I've tried adding [wheel removeAllActions]; before each touchesBegan:

CODE:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

    myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));


    myLabel.text = @"Speed: 0";
    myLabel.fontSize = 20;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50,
                                   CGRectGetMinY(self.frame));

    /* WHEEL CREATION */
    /*==============================================================================================*/
    wheel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wheel.png"];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);

    CGFloat offsetX = wheel.frame.size.width * wheel.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = wheel.frame.size.height * wheel.anchorPoint.y;

    wheel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 170);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 132 - offsetX, 276 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 122 - offsetX, 283 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 116 - offsetX, 272 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 108 - offsetX, 271 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100 - offsetX, 268 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 266 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 87 - offsetX, 261 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 86 - offsetX, 260 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 73 - offsetX, 263 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 72 - offsetX, 250 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 65 - offsetX, 246 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 58 - offsetX, 239 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 53 - offsetX, 234 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 48 - offsetX, 227 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 36 - offsetX, 225 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 39 - offsetX, 213 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 34 - offsetX, 206 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 32 - offsetX, 200 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 30 - offsetX, 194 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 27 - offsetX, 187 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 26 - offsetX, 183 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 15 - offsetX, 175 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 23 - offsetX, 166 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 22 - offsetX, 163 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 22 - offsetX, 154 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 22 - offsetX, 143 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 23 - offsetX, 133 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 16 - offsetX, 122 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 26 - offsetX, 117 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 27 - offsetX, 112 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 28 - offsetX, 108 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 31 - offsetX, 101 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 34 - offsetX, 96 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 37 - offsetX, 88 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 39 - offsetX, 85 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 36 - offsetX, 72 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 48 - offsetX, 71 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 51 - offsetX, 68 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 54 - offsetX, 63 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 60 - offsetX, 59 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 65 - offsetX, 54 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 71 - offsetX, 49 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 73 - offsetX, 37 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 85 - offsetX, 39 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 91 - offsetX, 36 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 97 - offsetX, 33 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 103 - offsetX, 30 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 109 - offsetX, 28 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 116 - offsetX, 26 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 123 - offsetX, 16 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 133 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 138 - offsetX, 22 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 145 - offsetX, 22 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 152 - offsetX, 22 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 160 - offsetX, 22 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 165 - offsetX, 23 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 176 - offsetX, 15 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 182 - offsetX, 26 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 190 - offsetX, 29 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 198 - offsetX, 31 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 203 - offsetX, 34 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 208 - offsetX, 37 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 213 - offsetX, 39 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 224 - offsetX, 36 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 226 - offsetX, 47 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 231 - offsetX, 51 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 236 - offsetX, 57 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 242 - offsetX, 61 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 245 - offsetX, 66 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 249 - offsetX, 72 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 262 - offsetX, 74 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 258 - offsetX, 86 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 264 - offsetX, 94 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 268 - offsetX, 101 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 270 - offsetX, 110 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 272 - offsetX, 117 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 283 - offsetX, 122 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 275 - offsetX, 132 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 276 - offsetX, 137 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 277 - offsetX, 145 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 277 - offsetX, 150 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 277 - offsetX, 156 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 276 - offsetX, 163 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 276 - offsetX, 167 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 283 - offsetX, 176 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 272 - offsetX, 183 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 271 - offsetX, 188 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 269 - offsetX, 195 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 266 - offsetX, 202 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 263 - offsetX, 208 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 260 - offsetX, 212 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 263 - offsetX, 225 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 250 - offsetX, 226 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 246 - offsetX, 233 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 241 - offsetX, 238 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 235 - offsetX, 243 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 229 - offsetX, 249 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 226 - offsetX, 250 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 225 - offsetX, 263 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 213 - offsetX, 259 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 207 - offsetX, 263 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 198 - offsetX, 267 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 191 - offsetX, 271 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 181 - offsetX, 273 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 175 - offsetX, 283 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 166 - offsetX, 275 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 159 - offsetX, 277 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 152 - offsetX, 277 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 145 - offsetX, 277 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 138 - offsetX, 277 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 133 - offsetX, 275 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    wheel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
    wheel.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    wheel.physicsBody.linearDamping = 100;


    /*======================================================================*/


    /* "FLAPPER" CREATION */
    /*==============================================================================================*/
    flapper = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"flapper.png"];
    flapper.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 92);
    flapper.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
    flapper.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    CGFloat flapperOffsetX = flapper.frame.size.width * flapper.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat flapperOffsetY = flapper.frame.size.height * flapper.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef flapperPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 4 - flapperOffsetX, 0 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 5 - flapperOffsetX, 0 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 6 - flapperOffsetX, 2 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 7 - flapperOffsetX, 8 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 7 - flapperOffsetX, 13 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 7 - flapperOffsetX, 17 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 21 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 24 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 29 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 33 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 37 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 8 - flapperOffsetX, 38 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 7 - flapperOffsetX, 40 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 6 - flapperOffsetX, 40 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 5 - flapperOffsetX, 40 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 3 - flapperOffsetX, 40 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 1 - flapperOffsetX, 39 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 1 - flapperOffsetX, 35 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 2 - flapperOffsetX, 15 - flapperOffsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(flapperPath, NULL, 3 - flapperOffsetX, 5 - flapperOffsetY
                         );

    CGPathCloseSubpath(flapperPath);

    flapper.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:flapperPath];
    flapper.physicsBody.mass = 5;
    flapper.physicsBody.linearDamping = 100;
    flapper.physicsBody.allowsRotation = TRUE;
    flapper.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = TRUE;

            /*==============================================================================================*/

        [self addChild:myLabel];
        [self addChild:wheel];
        [self addChild:flapper];
    }

    return self;
    }

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        //SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:10 duration:1];
        [wheel runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

        SKAction *slow = [SKAction speedBy:0.2 duration:5];
        [wheel runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:slow count:10]];
    }

    NSLog(@"reached end of touchesBegan");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question but for anyone looking at this with similar questions. I have created an open source spinning prize wheel in Spritekit and swift that uses physics for realistic movement and flapper control.

It allows the user to generates a random spin by pushing the center of the wheel or drag the wheel to spin using physics forces.

https://github.com/hsilived/SpinWheel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to "fake" the flapper.

Create several flappers that are bent by a different amount and swap in the correct flapper for a given position of the wheel.

There's no reason to make the flapper physically interact with the wheel — you can slow the wheel down with code. In fact, for so simple a set-up there's no need for physics body code at all.

Comment: Hmmm, how would I make it realistic? Is there a way to synch the animation of the flapper to the speed of the wheel? Also, do you have any idea why I can't spin the wheel again after the first spin?

Comment: Also, another thought, wouldn't it best to make them interact? Otherwise, how do I prevent the prize wheel from stopping at a mid-zone (aka, the pegs that separate the prizes and interact with the "flapper"?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be nicer if you just made a sprite for your flapper where the image can be one of several (10 or so) different "bent" positions. then all you will need to do is get the angle of your wheel and mod it by the number of frames you have and multiply it by Pi*2. That should work fine. I hope this makes sense.

Also, that wheel creation can a single line with CGPathAddArc instead of all those CGPathAddLineToPoint

as for the spinning, since you are using sprite kit, just use the physics stuff you get for free instead of using an SKAction.

There are two cases you should think about.
 1. when the user drags around the wheel, you need to rotate the wheel to match that movement instantly (no animation)
 2. when the user lets go, you can calculate the speed it was moving by using the touch event's previous point (part of the touch) and just turn that into an angular force to your wheel.

Comment: I actually have a sprite kit wheel that I made a while ago that works similar to this. I will see if I can find it for you. but here's a UIView version to get you started https://github.com/nathanfjohnson/SpinWheel

Comment: I actually already found that one! I've been using it while looking for something that fits my needs on the functionality end. If you find that Sprite Kit wheel, please let me know!